# Pandas: drop rows with a column value, & remove for other subrows

Tags: python, pandas

My question can best be explained visually.  There are many answers on how in a Pandas dataframe to remove rows with certain column values, but I am not sure the best way to deal with the other steps of what I want to do.

```
country series 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009

AFG     net m  ..   ..    5    ..  10
AFG     battle 100  50   55   60   100
AFG     GDP    200  100  150  200  250
AFG     info   ..   ..   ..   ..   ..  
AFG     life   60   ..    61  63   64
AFG     unemp  5.7  5.9  6.0  5.4  5.3
ALB     net m  ..   ..    5    ..  10
ALB     battle 100  50   55   60   100
ALB     GDP    200  100  150  200  250
ALB     info   ..   45   ..   99   ..  
ALB     life   78   ..    61  63   64
ALB     unemp  ..   ..   ..   ..   3.2
and so on for other countries
```

I would to check the series for each country where for each year column, at least 2 values exist.  If less than 2 values exist, remove that row.  But if it is removed for one country, remove it for all the other countries if the condition did not hold true for that country.

My output would be:

```
country series 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009

AFG     net m  ..   ..    5    ..  10
AFG     battle 100  50   55   60   100
AFG     GDP    200  100  150  200  250
AFG     life   60   ..    61  63   64
ALB     net m  ..   ..    5    ..  10
ALB     battle 100  50   55   60   100
ALB     GDP    200  100  150  200  250
ALB     life   78   ..    61  63   64
```

where info is removed for AFG because there were no values in the year columns, but also for ALB and all the other countries. unemp was removed because only one value existed for ALB, but also removed for all the other countries.

Thanks for your time and any feedback

Comment: Thanks a lot to all - StackOverflow is awesome.  All of the solutions worked and I understood them all.  It ends up that for all the countries I have, 5 rows result (that is, 5 have at least 2 values for each country) this also helps me to figure out what countries I can exclude and be able to have more than 5 features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
 '2005': ['..', '100', '200', '..', '60', '5.7', '..', '100', '200', '..', '78', '..'],
 '2006': ['..', '50', '100', '..', '..', '5.9', '..', '50', '100', '45', '..', '..'],
 '2007': ['5', '55', '150', '..', '61', '6.0', '5', '55', '150', '..', '61','..'],
 '2008': ['..', '60', '200', '..', '63', '5.4', '..', '60', '200', '99', '63', '..'],
 '2009': ['10', '100', '250', '..', '64', '5.3', '10', '100', '250', '..', '64', '3.2'],
 'country': ['AFG', 'AFG', 'AFG', 'AFG', 'AFG', 'AFG', 'ALB', 'ALB', 'ALB', 'ALB', 'ALB', 'ALB'],
 'series': ['net m', 'battle', 'GDP', 'info', 'life', 'unemp', 'net m', 'battle', 'GDP', 'info', 'life', 'unemp']},
columns=['country', 'series', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009']).replace('..', np.nan)
```

I choose to make a dummy column called `Count` just to show visually which rows to delete based on if their `Count` is less than `2`.

```
df1['Count'] = df1.loc[:, '2005':].count(axis=1)
   country  series 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009  Count
0      AFG   net m  NaN  NaN    5  NaN   10      2
1      AFG  battle  100   50   55   60  100      5
2      AFG     GDP  200  100  150  200  250      5
3      AFG    info  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN      0
4      AFG    life   60  NaN   61   63   64      4
5      AFG   unemp  5.7  5.9  6.0  5.4  5.3      5
6      ALB   net m  NaN  NaN    5  NaN   10      2
7      ALB  battle  100   50   55   60  100      5
8      ALB     GDP  200  100  150  200  250      5
9      ALB    info  NaN   45  NaN   99  NaN      2
10     ALB    life   78  NaN   61   63   64      4
11     ALB   unemp  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  3.2      1
```

Next is to check if the `series` value is in a list of values associated to rows that have `Count` less than `2`.  The `~` then excludes these from the result.

```
df1[~df1['series'].isin(df1[df1['Count'] < 2]['series'].tolist())]
#Produces:
   country  series 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009  Count
0      AFG   net m  NaN  NaN    5  NaN   10      2
1      AFG  battle  100   50   55   60  100      5
2      AFG     GDP  200  100  150  200  250      5
4      AFG    life   60  NaN   61   63   64      4
6      ALB   net m  NaN  NaN    5  NaN   10      2
7      ALB  battle  100   50   55   60  100      5
8      ALB     GDP  200  100  150  200  250      5
10     ALB    life   78  NaN   61   63   64      4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df1  = pd.DataFrame( [["AFG", "net m", "", "", 5, "", 10],
                      ["AFG", "battle", 100, 50 , 55, 60 , 100],
                     ["AFG", "GDP", 200, 100 , 150, 200 , 250],
                      ["AFG", "info", "", "" , "", "" , ""],
                      ["AFG", "life", 60, "" , 61, 63 , 64],
                      ["ALB", "net m", "", "", 5, "", 10],
                      ["ALB", "battle", 100, 50 , 55, 60 , 100],
                     ["ALB", "GDP", 200, 100 , 150, 200 , 250],
                      ["ALB", "info", "", 45 , "", 99 , ""],

                      ["ALB", "life", 78, "" , 61, 63 , 64],

                     ],columns = ["country", "series", 2005,2006,2007,2008,2009])
list_of_series_to_exclude = []
for i in df1["country"].unique(): #loop over unique countries
    for row in df1[df1["country"]==i].iterrows(): #loop over a slice of original dataframe, based on current country
        series = row[1][1] # keep track of current series
        years = pd.Series([x for x in row[1][2:]]) # year columns
        x = dict(years.value_counts(sort=True)) # get in dictionary form the counts for unique values in the year columns
        try:
            if x[''] > len(row[1][2:])-2: 
                list_of_series_to_exclude.append(series)
        except KeyError:
            pass #Row doesnt have blank value
final_set = set(df1["series"])
set_to_sub = set(list_of_series_to_exclude)

final_list = list(final_set-set_to_sub)
df1 = df1[df1["series"].isin(final_list)]
```

Output:

```
print df1
 country  series 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009
0     AFG   net m              5        10
1     AFG  battle  100   50   55   60  100
2     AFG     GDP  200  100  150  200  250
4     AFG    life   60        61   63   64
5     ALB   net m              5        10
6     ALB  battle  100   50   55   60  100
7     ALB     GDP  200  100  150  200  250
9     ALB    life   78        61   63   64
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the empty fields are represented as NaNs. You can first use [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html) and [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) to extract the rows with less than two valid values, and use the associated "series" values to filter the original DataFrame with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
mask = (~df[range(2005,2010)].isnull()).sum(axis=1) < 2
print df[~df.series.isin(df[mask].series)]
```

Output:

```
  country  series  2005  2006  2007  2008  2009
0     AFG   net m   NaN   NaN     5   NaN    10
1     AFG  battle   100    50    55    60   100
2     AFG     GDP   200   100   150   200   250
4     AFG    life    60   NaN    61    63    64
5     ALB   net m   NaN   NaN     5   NaN    10
6     ALB  battle   100    50    55    60   100
7     ALB     GDP   200   100   150   200   250
9     ALB    life    78   NaN    61    63    64
```